# ACL User group deny in CQ5

Tags: aem, acl

For a page in CQ5 ,have added permission as deny for jcr:write ,for particular user AA .The user AA is restricted to write on the page. But when i added a user group(user AA is a member of the group) with deny action for jcr:write its not working, user AA is able to write .

Comment: Could you post your content structure (with acl nodes)?

Comment: Is the user part of another groups? Maybe the group? Working with denies is not the best approach. Are you working with deny on jcr:write or rep:write?

Comment: User is not member of other group. Now it got worked . Simple i restarted the Instance :) Thank you for the inputs.